# Ubuntu from a PC to another

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, windows-10, 18.10, preinstallation

So I had this old Laptop that have 2 SSD's one(this was inside of the laptop) with Windows and another(one I bought) with a partition with Ubuntu. Now I bought a Desktop and I want two put this second SSD with ubuntu on my new Desktop. So I want two stay with 1xSSD(alreay with Win10) 1xSSD(from old laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed) It is possible?

Comment: it is possible but if you are not familiar with EFI/UEFI, video drivers, dpkg-reconfigure and grub update, you would better go for a fresh new install of Ubuntu on your desktop

Comment: Anything is hard if you are not familiar with the concepts and the execution. We don't know your skill level or your comfort level. Go ahead and try moving the SSD and see what happens. Maybe it will work. We gently suggest a good backup of both SSDs before starting.